# Issues with Wordpress 3.9.6 media libraries on XAMPP

Tags: uploads, media, media-library

I am having issues with the media library of Wordpress on my local Xampp installation of Wordpress 3.9.6.

- Uploading files to the media library takes a long time and occassionally fails.  However when I go back the images are there.
- Can't upload media files via adding media to pages.  Getting message "An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later."
- When trying to select a featured image of adding an image from the media library to a page the media library does not show the thumbnails

I am using a custom child theme.  Have tried changing themes and it does not work.  Have also tried disabling plugins and even installed a fresh version from scratch but still won't do it.  Could you advice.

Cheers

Comment: updated to latest version of WordPress.

Comment: Does the same happen with the latest version of WordPress??

Comment: Have just tried with a fresh Wordpress 4.2.2 install.  Same theme and plugin settings that was breaking my local 3.9.6 install, media library works no problem at all